# Return input string backwards, recursively

Tags: java, string, recursion, methods

I'm trying to make a recursive method that returns a word backwards and puts dashes between it.
Here is my code:

```
public static String expand (String word)
{
    if (word.length () <= 1)
    {
        return word; //Return Original word
    }
    else
    {
        return word.substring (word.length () + 1 , word.length ()) + "-" + expand (word.substring (word.length ()));
    }
}
```

It's not working; it is just returning one letter with a dash. How can I fix it?

Comment: Why do you use recursion for that ? It would be so simple to do in a direct way.

Comment: Cannot understand.can you please add input and expected ouput

Comment: Cf. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse%28%29

Comment: It's hard to answer that question without simply typing the code for you (which is easy enough).

Comment: What do you think is left of a String after calling `.substring(word.length())`?

Comment: It is a homework problem and the solution is pretty simple.  Better for OP to learn the lesson.

Comment: Just reading [substring documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) would answer this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static String expand(String word) {
    if (word.length() <= 1) {
        return word; //Return Original word
    } else {
        return word.substring(word.length() - 1) + "-" + expand(word.substring(0, word.length() - 1));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: As I pointed out in my comment to his question, his mistake was using `.substring(word.length())` which yields the empty String. You corrected it to `word.substring(0, word.length() - 1)`

Answer (score 1):

you could do it with out using recursive, just like this:

```
String s = "value";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = (s.length() - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
        sb.append(s.charAt(i));
        sb.append("-");
    }

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```